# Why does C not have an snwprintf function?

Tags: c

Does anyone know why there is no `snwprintf` function in the C standard library?

I am aware of `swprintf`, but that doesn't have the same semantics of a true, `wchar_t` version of `snprintf`.  As far as I can tell, there is no easy way to implement an `snwprintf` function using `[v]swprintf`:

Unlike `snprintf`, `swprintf` does not return the necessary buffer size; if the supplied buffer is insufficient, it simply returns -1.  This is indistinguishable from failure due to encoding errors, so I can't keep retrying with progressively larger buffers hoping that it eventually will succeed.

I suppose I could set the last element of the buffer to be non-NUL, call `swprintf`, and assume that truncation occurred if that element is NUL afterward.  However, is that guaranteed to work?  The standard does not specify what state the buffer should be in if `swprintf` fails. (In contrast, `snprintf` describes which characters are written and which are discarded.)

Comment: I think you're right that you can't assume anything about the contents of the buffer when `swprintf` fails. Could you use `errno`? I know it would work on POSIX but C by itself may not require `EILSEQ` for encoding errors...?

Comment: @R..: Thanks. `errno` is an interesting idea.  I think if I want a portable solution, though, I might have to modify an actual `vswprintf` implementation from FreeBSD. =(

Comment: Keep in mind, reimplementing a printf-family function is probably a bad idea, because you cannot guarantee that you duplicate all the locale-specific functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the answer given by Larry Jones [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_frm/thread/5c1686a4338eaaa4/0e7c7ce3950aa2fb?lnk=gst&q=snwprintf#0e7c7ce3950aa2fb).

Essentially, `swprintf` was added in C95 while `snprintf` was added in C99 and since many implementations already returned the number of required characters (for `snprintf`) and it seemed a useful thing to do, that was the behavior that was standardized.  They didn't think that behavior was important enough to break backwards compatibility with `swprintf` by adding it (which was added without that behavior several years earlier).

Comment: I agree that they couldn't break backwards compatibility by changing `swprintf`, but they could have added a new `snwprintf` function.

Comment: Apparently they didn't feel it would be worth it to add another function just to implement this behavior.

Comment: Actually, many historic versions of `snprintf` prior to standardization had the same broken "return -1" behavior as `swprintf`. The committee deemed it broken and specified the correct behavior instead, which broke compatibility with the old Unix (SUSv2) standard.

Comment: Actually, POSIX too seems self-contradictory in this regard. It requires: "If n or more wide characters were requested to be written...set errno to indicate the error.", but `EOVERFLOW` is only documented as occurring if `n>INT_MAX` or if the resulting string would be longer than `INT_MAX`. No value of `errno` is specified for the case when the output does not fit in `n` characters...