# Correct use of string storage in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, unicode, character-encoding, posix

Popular software developers and companies ([Joel Spolsky, **Fog Creek software**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)) tend to use **wchar_t** for Unicode character *storage* when writing C or C++ code. When and how should one use **char** and **wchar_t** in respect to good coding practices?

I am particularly interested in **POSIX** compliance when writing software that leverages Unicode.

When using **wchar_t**, you can look up characters in an array of wide characters on a per-character or per-array-element basis:

```
/* C code fragment */
const wchar_t *overlord = L"ov€rlord";
if (overlord[2] == L'€')
    wprintf(L"Character comparison on a per-character basis.\n");
```

*How can you compare unicode bytes (or characters) when using **char**?*

So far my preferred way of comparing strings and characters of type **char** in C often looks like this:

```
/* C code fragment */
const char *mail[] = { "ov€rlord@masters.lt", "ov€rlord@masters.lt" };
if (mail[0][2] == mail[1][2] && mail[0][3] == mail[1][3] && mail[0][3] == mail[1][3])
    printf("%s\n%zu", *mail, strlen(*mail));
```

This method scans for the byte equivalent of a unicode character. The Unicode Euro symbol **€** takes up 3 bytes. Therefore one needs to compare three char array bytes to know if the Unicode characters match. Often you need to know the size of the character or string you want to compare and the bits it produces for the solution to work. This does not look like a good way of handling Unicode at all. *Is there a better way of comparing strings and character elements of type **char**?*

In addition, when using **wchar_t**, how can you scan the file contents to an array? The function **fread** does not seem to produce valid results.

Comment: Unicode in C++: don't use `wchar_t`, use a proper Unicode library.

Comment: `tend to use wchar_t for Unicode character encoding`. No; they use it for Unicode character _storage_, and there is a big difference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::wstring VS std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Unfortunately, the C/C++ standards do not require `wchar_t` to be capable of storing Unicode characters, and do not specify how you would figure out the encoding if it does store Unicode characters.

Comment: The reason Joel Spolsky can use `wchar_t` is because he's not writing portable code and not targeting POSIX: he's assuming that `wchar_t` is UCS-2, which is how it works with "Visual Basic, COM, and Windows NT/2000/XP."  Not only is UCS-2 obsolete, the `wchar_t` type is nearly useless on POSIX systems.  Few libraries use it, so the only thing you'll ever do with `wchar_t` is turn it into something else (probably UTF-16 or UTF-8).  You can't manipulate it easily because you can't portably assume how it's encoded.  It's like some big joke the standards committees perpetrated.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: A joke indeed. `wchar_t` is essentially a second-class citizen.  For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693479/why-does-c-not-have-an-snwprintf-function

Comment: Also, nobody is really using UTF-16. The obvious target group for UTF-16 (people who speak CJK, because UTF-16 is more compact for those character ranges than UTF-8, UTF-32 or schemes like SCSU, BOCU) use different encodings entirely!

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Quite. It's not particularly _good_ at storing "Unicode" characters, but that is what people "tend" to use it for nonetheless :)

Comment: @Dietrich: wchar_t in Windows stores UTF-16. wchar_t on some (most) *nix platforms stores UTF-32. So no UCS-2, and not obsolete.

Comment: @Mr Lister: actually, pretty much everybody uses UTF-16: Mac OS X, Windows, KDE, Qt, Java. The only areas using utf-8 internally are the some of the Linux/*nix CRT (and in many cases without "knowing" is utf-8, just moving bytes around).

Comment: So, wchar_t is not a joke. It is indeed a second class citizen because the standard C/C++ runtime library obstinately refuses to acknowledge that all the APIs operating on char_t need equivalent APIs on wchar_t (or uchar16_t, or uchar32_t, or anything other than "bunch of bytes").

Comment: @MihaiNita: This is not a discussion about UTF-16, this is a discussion about `wchar_t`.  You are right that those APIs use UTF-16, but only on Windows is that the same thing as `wchar_t`; so you can't do much with `wchar_t` on Mac OS X because it's UTF-32.  Kind of disingenuous to mention KDE and dismiss UTF-8 as irrelevant considering it's used for major parts of many Linux desktops, e.g., Pango and Gtk.  The joke about `wchar_t` is that it's supposed to be portable but it's actually less portable than, say, `unsigned short`.  At least you know `unsigned short` is 16 bits on POSIX.

Comment: @MihaiNita: Java is also irrelevant, since we are talking about `wchar_t` which is part of the C and C++ standards.  Java does not have a `wchar_t` type.

Comment: There are plenty of myths on this subject. As others said, those "Popular software developers" aren't targeting anything but windows. Once you need to write portable code, using [UTF-8 encoded narrow string everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/) is the sanest way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you know that you're dealing with unicode, neither `char` nor `wchar_t` are appropriate as their sizes are compiler/platform-defined. For example, `wchar_t` is 2 bytes on Windows (MSVC), but 4 bytes on Linux (GCC). The C11 and C++11 standards have been a bit more rigorous, and define two new character types (`char16_t` and `char32_t`) with associated literal prefixes for creating UTF-{8, 16, 32} strings.

If you need to store and manipulate unicode characters, you should use a library that is designed for the job, as neither the pre-C11 nor pre-C++11 language standards have been written with unicode in mind. There are a [few to choose from](http://unicode.org/resources/libraries.html), but [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) is quite popular (and supports C, C++, and Java).

Comment: Even C++11 is quite light on the unicode stuff. Beyond mandating a few types and standard conversions between utf8/16/32 you won't find anything like collation, comparison, normalization, etc.

Comment: Just as an addition, I think C11 here tries to be in sync with C++1 and introduces the same new `char??_t` types.

Comment: Yes, C11 is in sync with C++11 for these types/literals.

Answer (score 0):

> I am particularly interested in **POSIX** compliance when writing software
>   that leverages Unicode.

In this case, you'll probably want to use UTF-8 (with `char`) as your preferred Unicode string type.  POSIX doesn't have a lot of functions for working with `wchar_t` — that's mostly a Windows thing.

> This method scans for the byte equivalent of a unicode character. The
>   Unicode Euro symbol € takes up 3 bytes. Therefore one needs to compare
>   three char array bytes to know if the Unicode characters match. Often
>   you need to know the size of the character or string you want to
>   compare and the bits it produces for the solution to work.

No, you don't.  You just compare the bytes.  Iff the bytes match, the strings match.  `strcmp` works just as well with UTF-8 as it does with any other encoding.

Unless you want something like a case-insensitive or accent-insensitive comparison, in which case you'll need a proper Unicode library.

Answer (score 0):

You should never-ever compare bytes, or even code points, to decide if strings are equal. That's because of a lot of strings can be identical from user perspective without being identical from code point perspective.