# swprintf truncation causes unexpected output

Tags: c++, printf

I'm fixing legacy code that runs on linux and windows and in some cases buffers that are supposed to contain formatted content are smaller than that content.

The code uses swprintf which according to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf)

> size  -   up to size - 1 characters may be written, plus the null terminator

Will indeed truncate the string, but while trying it on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e674ccafeac7dd2) I encountered unexpected results:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <cwchar> 

int main()
{

    wchar_t wide[5];

    std::swprintf(wide, sizeof wide/sizeof *wide, L"%ls", L"111111111");

    std::wcout << wide;
}
```

will result in `1111??` but

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <cwchar> 

int main()
{

    wchar_t wide[20];

    std::swprintf(wide, sizeof wide/sizeof *wide, L"%ls", L"111111111");

    std::wcout << wide;
}
```

Works just fine.

What's wrong ?

P.S. 
I wish I could change everything to C++ streams/string but I can't, `wchar_t` arrays are used everywhere

Comment: Just because you use a lot of arrays doesn't mean you can't use stream I/O. `std::ostream` has a [`write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) method that you can pass (a piece of) an array to

Comment: I mean, it's not like standard library stream IO is a paragon of API design.

Comment: @Spinkoo that is perfectly fine, `swprintf()` takes a buffer size for bounds checking and truncating. It sounds more like the OP's STL library has a bug in its `swprintf()` implementation where it is not writing out the terminating null correctly if the buffer is filled to the max allowed chars.

Comment: ah yes i agree with you

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not convinced that's a bug, though IMO it's kind of underspecified in C. See my answer - thoughts welcome!

Comment: @RemyLebeau sadly `copy` doesn't null terminate  so it's not a very good option as it would force me to "remember" to do it myself which is something I'd rather the function did

Comment: @Darius who said anything about using `copy`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau MB probably had another tab open :). However the function you liked to writes an array to a stream and not the other way around IIRC, I'm trying to populate `wchar_t some_array[SIZE];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***tl;dr:*** For one reason or another, those null-termination semantics are dependent on the function call succeeding, and for `swprintf` it only succeeds if the buffer is *big enough. Hence, the array in your first attempt is not null-terminated.*

---

This is subtle, but `swprintf` isn't like `snprintf`. It doesn't write "at most N-1 characters" and consider that successful in all cases.

Here's what the same documentation says about the return value from `swprintf`:

> **Return value:** Number of wide characters written (not counting the terminating null wide character) if successful or negative value if an encoding error occurred or if the number of characters to be generated was equal or greater than size (including when size is zero)

And, indeed, [your attempt returns -1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/779d0fc1f13b6101).

From this (and from the note underneath that quote) we can ascertain that `swprintf` considers the operation a *failure* if there weren't enough bytes in the provided output buffer. It won't overrun that buffer, but it also may not complete its work, and its work includes writing a NULL terminator. Without that NULL terminator, the `wchar_t*` you're [effectively] passing to `std::wcout` will run out of bounds and your program has undefined behaviour.

---

I concede that this, on a casual reading, would seem to contradict the semantics surrounding the `size` parameter, for which C11 states:

> No more than `n` wide characters are written, including a terminating null wide character, which is always added (unless`n` is zero).

…without stating any condition on whether the function call was otherwise successful.

There may be scope for calling this an editorial defect in the standard, or an implementation bug. *But* even if neither were true, your function call was deemed unsuccessful, and I don't think you should rely on the outcome accordingly.

We can at least see that the *libc* intent matches the above run-down, from [this manual page on Formatted Output Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Formatted-Output-Functions.html):

> The return value is the number of characters generated for the given input, excluding the trailing null. If not all output fits into the provided buffer a negative value is returned. You should try again with a bigger output string. Note: this is different from how snprintf handles this situation.

---

You're going to have to heed the aforementioned note:

> While narrow strings provide std::snprintf, which makes it possible to determine the required output buffer size, there is no equivalent for wide strings, and in order to determine the buffer size, the program may need to call std::swprintf, check the result value, and reallocate a larger buffer, trying again until successful.

…or switch to some other functionality altogether.

Comment: Yes, I see how that could be the interpretation, when you say other functionality, do you mean there's another portable way of copying `wchar_t* `based strings with truncation ?

Comment: @Darius Honestly, I didn't look into what a possible alternative might be - left as an exercise for the reader, sorry ;)

Comment: @Darius There may be some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3693479/560648) (where someone is looking for said alternative); at the very least, they (and the folks on the linked comp.std.c discussion) agree that there is a problem.