# Why the different behavior of snprintf vs swprintf?

Tags: c, c99

The C standard states the following from the standard library function `snprintf`:

> "The `snprintf` function is equivalent to `fprintf`, except that the
> output is written into an array (specified by arguments) rather than
> to a stream. If `n` is zero, nothing is written, and `s` may be a null
> pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the `n-1`st are discarded
> rather than being written to the array, and a null character is
> written at the end of the characters actually written into the array.
> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
> undefined."
>
> "The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would
> have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the
> terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error
> occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written
> if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`."

Compare it to the statement about `swprintf`:

> "The `swprintf` function is equivalent to `fwprintf`, except that the
> argument `s` specifies an array of wide characters into which the
> generated output is to be written, rather than written to a stream. No
> more than `n` wide characters are written, including a terminating null
> wide character, which is always added (unless `n` is zero)."
>
> "The `swprintf` function returns the number of wide characters written
> in the array, not counting the terminating null wide character, or a
> negative value if an encoding error occurred or if `n` or more wide
> characters were requested to be written."

At first glance it may seem like `snprintf` and `swprintf` are complete equivalent to each other, the latter merely handling wide strings and the former narrow strings. However, that's not the case. While `snprintf` returns the number of characters that would have been written if `n` had been large enough, `swprintf` returns a negative value in this case (which means that you can't know how many characters would have been written if there had been enough space). This makes the two functions not fully interchangeable, because their behavior is different in this regard (and thus the latter can't be used for some thing that the former can, such as evaluating how long the output buffer would need to be, before actually creating it.)

Why would they make this difference? I suppose the behavior of `swprintf` makes the implementation more efficient when `n` is too small, but still, why the difference? I don't think it's even a question of `snprintf` being older and thus "legacy" and "dragging the weight of its history, which can't be changed later" and `swprintf` being newer and thus free to be improved, because both were introduced in C99.

There is, however, another significantly subtler difference between the two specifications. If you notice, the specifications are not merely carbon-copies of each other, with the only difference being the return value. That's another, much subtler difference, and that's the somewhat ambiguous behavior of what happens if `n` is too small for the string-to-be-printed.

The specification for `snprintf` quite clearly states that the output will be written up to `n-1` characters even when `n` is too small, and the null character will be written at the end of it always. The specification of `swprintf` *almost* states this... except it leaves it ambiguous in its specification of the return value.

More specifically a negative return value is used to signal that an error occurred while trying to write the string to the destination. A negative value is also returned when `n` was too small. It's left ambiguous whether this is actually considered an error situation or not. This is significant because if it's considered an error, then the implementation is free to not write all, or anything, into the destination, because it can be signaling "an error occurred, the output is invalid". The first paragraph of the specification makes it sound like at most `n-1` characters are always written, and an ending null character is always written ("which is always added"), but the second paragraph about the return value leaves it ambiguous whether this is actually an error situation and whether the implementation can choose not to write those things in this case.

This is significant because the glibc implementation of `swprintf` does not write the final null character when `n` is too small, making the result an invalid string. While I can't find definitive information on this, I have got the impression that the developers of glibc have interpreted the standard in such a manner that they don't have to write the final null character (or anything) to the output because this is an error situation.

The thing is that the standard seems to be very ambiguous and vague in this regard. Is it a correct interpretation? Or are they misinterpreting? Why would the standard leave it this ambiguous?

My interpretation differs from that of the glibc developers. I understand the second paragraph to mean:

> A negative value is returned if:
>
> 1. an encoding error occurred, or
> 2. `n` or more wide characters were requested to be written.

I don't see how this could be interpreted as `n` being too small being considered an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693479/why-does-c-not-have-an-snwprintf-function

Comment: "glibc implementation of swprintf does not write the final null character when n is too small," -->  is not compliant.  "No more than n wide characters are written, including a terminating null wide character, which is **always** added (unless n is zero)." is not  ambiguous other than where on error, but not if.